# How to align text with non-continuous label on Zebra Printer (ZPL)?

Tags: printing, label, zebra-printers, text-alignment, zpl

I am trying to print the following text onto a label using a Zebra Printer:

```
Best Buy Date
00/00/00
SomeProductName
```

However the printer doesn't seem to detect the gap between the labels as it should when using `MNW` (Media Tracking, Web).  It prints as if it is continuous and the text is scattered all over the labels/gaps.  The labels are 1.25x1 inch labels.

Here is my ZP:

```
^XA
^MNW
^MMT
^FX Example of comment
^CFA,30
^FS
^FO0,30
^FDBest By Date
^FS)
^FS
^FO0,60
^FD11/23/2016
^FS)
^FS
^FO0,90
^FD
Clams
^FS)
^CFA,30
^XZ
```

I've looked over the documentation here: https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/en-us/software/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf

but couldn't identify what I was doing wrong.  Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can focus just on notch settings for printer.
I don't have experience with zebra printers, but I had a printer with notch settings. Try to type notch in zebra documentation and ^LL command.

Hope this helps a bit,
best regards